# Read from File into an Array

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script that does various stuff but when it starts, it checks if there has been a crash and so tries to load its variables from a logfile.

The log file has the following format:

```
1stline: var1:var2:var3:var4:var5 # : is a delimeter
2ndline: number                   # [0-9]
3rdline: var6:var7:var8           # : is a delimeter
```

So as you can tell I have 9 variables that I wish to load from this file if there has been a crash.

I am trying to write some code  in bash to do it but I am getting stuck.

For instance my Idea is to create an array, and add every variable which is read from the logfile there. But I am having troubles writing this code.

```
if [ -s ${crashfile} ] # file exists => crash has occured
then
    declare -a loadvars
    while IFS= read -r line 

        # What do I do in here ? 

    done < ${crashfile}

else # file doesn't exist => cold start

# bla 
# bla
# bla

fi
```

The problem is focused inside the first while loop. Meaning I am thinking that I have to create another while loop to tokenize the string accordingly? But then again, the second line has only a number with no delimeter so this should  be treated carefully aswell?

I can do it with python/C whatever but the point is to do it with bash.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give an example of input and the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a temporary array:

```
vars=()
while IFS=: read -ra temp; do
    vars+=("${temp[@]}")
done < file
printf '<%s>\n' "${vars[@]}"
```

For your sample (except `#` comments), it outputs:

```
<var1>
<var2>
<var3>
<var4>
<var5>
<number>
<var6>
<var7>
<var8>
```

Comment: I tried your code (even though I would like some clarification on what the **read -ra temp** does) in my file which is the following: 1stline: **exhaustive:0:targeted:0:noenc** 2ndline: **0** 3rdline: **0:0:0** and the output is the following **0 targeted 0 noenc 0 0**. So the first line is read after the first  variable and the two last characters are missing I suppose. By using my example file I get **var2 var3 var4 var5 var7 var8**

Comment: @Broxigar updated the script. `IFS=: read -ra temp` reads a line from stdin, splits it by :'s and populates array named temp with resulting bits

Comment: `IFS=$':\n' read -r -d '' -a vars` would read it all at once without looping

Comment: @Lea you're right, upvoted your answer already. I thought OP had labels before variables (as seen in the sample), that's why I used a loop at first

Answer (score 1):

If you are really sure of your 9 variables:

```sh
IFS=$':\n' read -r -d '' var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 number var6 var7 var8

printf '<%s>\n' "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" "$var4" "$var5" "$number" "$var6" "$var7" "$var8"
```

If you need to read an undefined amount of values, then use an array:

```sh
IFS=$':\n' read -r -d '' -a vars

printf '<%s>\n' "${vars[@]}"
```